# Running multiple Map Tasks on Single Node Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently running Hadoop 2.6.0 on one node of Ubuntu Server edition. I have tried running a mapreduce program using the python streaming option through "hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar".

I have four input files to be mapped and reduced, however no matter how many settings I change, I can only get 1 map process to start. Only using 1 core at 100%.

I have tried the following,

the "mapred-site.xml" is set as the following

```
    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
            <value>localhost:54311</value>
            <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task.
            </description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.maps</name>
            <value>8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job</name>
            <value>200000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
            <value>8</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
            <value>8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.running.map.limit</name>
            <value>-1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
            <value>8</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried modifying the input parameters in the streaming `.jar` file, more specifically the following,
`-D mapred.map.tasks=8 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=8` However, no luck with this either. Any insight would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Hadoop Ouput

```
15/04/18 10:09:12 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [/home/map.py, /home/reduce.py] [] /tmp/streamjob6267815363585502110.jar tmpDir=null
15/04/18 10:09:13 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/04/18 10:09:13 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/04/18 10:09:13 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:60
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1597598798_0001
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/home/map.py as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1429384154725/map.py
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/home/reduce.py as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1429384154726/reduce.py
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1597598798_0001
15/04/18 10:09:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1597598798_0001_m_000000_0
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/data1GB/data-0.txt:0+16777216
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 8
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/usr/local/hadoop/bin/./map.py]
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.work.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.output.dir
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=10/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=100/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=266/1
15/04/18 10:09:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1597598798_0001 running in uber mode : false
```

Comment: How large is the data file? Hadoop creates map task based on the number of blocks among all the files to be analyzed; the reason is a block is passed to each mapper. Thus, if the file is smaller than the configured block size, most probably only one map is run. By modifying the related configuration parameters you are only giving hints to Hadoop, but it is not mandatory to use such values.

Comment: I've tried with a 100mb total filesize, divided among 4 files so 25mb each file. Is there anyway to edit the block size? I can also try with a 1GB file, divided to 250mb each file.

Comment: `dfs.blocksize` at hdfs-defaukt.xml. By defaukt it is 128MB, reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Comment: Nope no luck, I've edited the "hdfs-site.xml" and changed the default blocksize to fit my filesizes, of 25mb each, however still no luck, there is still only one map process running

Comment: I've also just tried using a larger file, a 1GB file divided up into 4 files, that way it would be way over the default, however still no advil.

Comment: Can you edit the question and print the output traces of the MR job? Just to see if there is some message regarding the number of file splits.

Comment: This is the output trace, thank you so much!

Comment: Is your input data compressed using compression algorithms like gzip or snappy etc. MapReduce cannot split files compressed through certain compression algorithms hence only one mapper is spawned.  after you changed dfs.blocksize did you restart HDFS and moved files to HDFS ? I beleive change in block size won't have any effect on existing files.

Comment: Tried all of the above, still no luck. My data is also not compressed, it is just a plain binary file.

Comment: @RichardCheung Did you get any luck in running multiple map and reduce tasks? I am also trying the same with no luck.